# Rails - Download multiple files at same time using send_file in a each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendfile

I want to download a file for each value in my array in a loop.

I have two methods in my class:

```
def test
  testarray = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

  testarray.each do |value|
    download_file(value)
  end

end 

def download_file(value)

  send_file("public/downloads/test/" +  value  +".pdf", :filename => value + ".pdf", :type => "application/pdf", :diposition => "inline")

end
```

But when I call my test method, only the last element of my array is downloaded. The console prints the following:

```
 Sent file public/downloads/shapefiles/test1.pdf (0.1ms)
 Sent file public/downloads/shapefiles/test2.pdf (0.1ms)
 Sent file public/downloads/shapefiles/test3.pdf (0.1ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

But my browser downloads only the last file, in this case, the `test3.pdf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send_file` actually instructs the server to send a file, not sends it itself. For example if properly configured nginx is used - rails will only issue `X-Accel-Redirect` header, all other file handling will be done by nginx. Other setups behave generally the same (but without a reverse proxy file upload still will block some ruby process/thread)

That's why only last file is being sent.

So to download multiple files they should be packed into one. You can use nginx_mod_zip to create zip on the fly using technique similar to X-accel-redirect